# Flex is not splitting components equally in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to make a layout like this:

[image]

In order to do so, I've made two components named `HalfWidthFullHeightCard` and `HalfWithHalfHeightCard`.

I've created the `HalfWidthFullHeightCell` component as?

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={pressEvent}>
            <ImageBackground
                source={sourcePath}
                imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 8, resizeMode: 'cover', width: '100%' }}
                style={styles.halfWidthCard}>
                <Text style={styles.halfWidthCardHeading}>{heading}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.halfWidthCardText}>{cardText}</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
        </TouchableOpacity>
...
    halfWidthCard: {
        backgroundColor: colors.brightYellow,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 8,
    },
```

Based on the `cardText` the width of the card is calculated automatically and in the `halfWidthCardText` StyleSheet I've only had `padding: 10`

Next for `HalfWithHalfHeightCard` everything is the same except for the styling which is:

```
...

    smallHalfWidthCard: {
        backgroundColor: colors.brightYellow,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    smallHalfWidthCardHeading: {
        padding: 10,
    },
    smallHalfWidthCardText: {
        padding: 10,
    },
```

Where I'm putting both of these components together I'm doing:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{padding: 15}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                <HalfWidthFullHeightCell />
                <View>
                    <HalfWithHalfHeightCell />
                    <HalfWithHalfHeightCell />
                </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Now there are two problems:

[image]

1. Consider the gray area as the width of the device. The `HalfWidthFullHeightCard` takes 100% of the space and
2. The `HalfWithHalfHeightCard` are outside of the screen and also not of the same height as `HalfWidthFullHeightCard`.

So, how can I make these components flexible so that they adapt to the layout as screen size changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have made it like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.WholeBox}>
        <View style={styles.Block}></View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={styles.Block}></View>
          <View style={styles.Block}></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  WholeBox: {
    width: ScreenWidth,
    height: 300,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  Block: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#DDA73A',
    margin: 6,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
});
```

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/flexbox-example)